# Any non Deep Learning python packages for sequence classification.?

Tags: python, regression, multiclass-classification, sequence

Stats model or any other machine learning python packages for doing sequence classification(that can be multi class) and sequence prediction (Both next step and regression).

PS : Input data will be n number of sequences with their respective target (class/regression)

Also each sequences having finite number of events like E1,E2 ..

Comment: Are the sequences of fixed length?

Comment: nope. It will be of varying length. Can we pad.?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using Conditional Random Fields? I had used it for my thesis some years ago and papers from Prof. Sunita Sarawagi were a great resource for me. You can use the [CRFsuite](http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/) library which also offers a python wrapper.

Comment: Does this handles if target is regression.? Because i have already tried [seqlearn](https://github.com/larsmans/seqlearn), which uses HMM and classifies it. But the real problem here is conversion of class specific functions to regression value

Comment: Do you really have a regression problem to solve or is it more of a multi-class classification problem?

Comment: yes it involves regression too